# Is there a way to lock bones property from getting keyed. In Auto Key mode?

Tags: animation, rigging

If lock the property right now it just prevents me from manipulating it but when i key it keys all the location rotation and position channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **Blender User Preferences** there are options under the **Editing** tab for **Keyframing**. Have you tried the **Only Insert Needed** toggle or the **Only Insert Available** toggle? That should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a way if you are using the default keying sets in Blender.

But, what you want can be achieved by creating and using custom keying sets.

1. Add only properties that you want to be keyed to a custom keying set.
2. Choose that keying set as the one to be used when auto keying / manual keying

[[Animating in 2.5] Getting to grips with Keying Sets](http://aligorith.blogspot.in/2010/12/animating-in-25-getting-to-grips-with.html)

Comment: Yes i am using keying sets already. but its really tedious to create the keying set for the first time for the rig. But i was expeting some thing like thats there in maya keyable and non keyable property that can be change..Thanks for your reply