# Is it possible to exclude a bone from automatic keyframing?

Tags: animation, bones, keyframes

I have a bone I use as a switch but I don't want it to keyframe while in automatic keyframing mode, in my case in visual LocRot.

Is there a way to disable keyframes for this bone to eliminate it from automatic keying?

Comment: Use keying sets https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html?highlight=key%20set

Comment: @cegaton I look forward to hearing how that is done.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/is-there-a-way-to-lock-bones-property-from-getting-keyed-in-auto-key-mode/1270#1270 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7636/what-is-a-keying-set-and-how-does-it-fit-into-the-animation-workflow/7639#7639

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since automatic keyframing inserts keyframes for all the objects/bones in your 3d view, the easiest way is to take the bones you don't want keyframed and remove them from the 3d view. You can do that by hiding them, or add them to a bone layer that you hide when not animating that switch.

Comment: To use the bone I would have to see it, and I'm trying to avoid making a keyframe while manipulating it, so I don't see what you mean by hiding it?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. This switch bone is used to control another part of your rig?

Comment: I"ll call this a NO to the question and give up at this point. Obviously now, if I don't even know what a keying set is or does this is problematic.